# What is the scope of a block-level variable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string, scope

Consider the following code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
   Dim str As String = str & " Kratika "
Next
```

When I attach the debugger and check the value of `str` at `i = 10`, I see the following:

```
 Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika  Kratika
```

Why is it concatenating the previous value? I would expect that the variable would be set to `kratika` each time, because each time it will declare a new String object, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

As you mention in a comment to another answer, it's probably easier to see using integers rather than string concatenation:

```
Sub Main()
  For i As Integer = 0 To 5
     Dim j As Integer = j + 1
     Console.WriteLine(j.ToString())
  Next
End Sub
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

To learn why, we turn to the documentation, specifically the section on [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx). The `j` variable that you've declared is at *block* scope, because it is declared inside of the `For` block. However, variables that are declared at block scope still retain their values for the entire duration of their containing procedure. As the documentation says in a note:

> Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

So what's happening is that each time you re-enter the `For` block, `j` still has its previous value. Because the right-side of the equals sign is evaluated first, that old value of `j` is incremented by 1, and then stored in `j` (effectively erasing the old contents of `j`).

Comment: @CodeGray would you please review this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937392/object-of-interop-word-document-class-is-null-on-windows-server-2008-word-open

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have use `str & " Kratika "` inside the loop.If you expect only  `" Kratika "` every time Then use only `Dim str As String = " Kratika "` inside the loop.

Now check again

Comment: thanks for reply my doubt is why it is adding previous value of string `kratika`

Comment: yes but with declaring you are using & operator IT always concat with previous value.

Comment: Dim str As String = " Kratika "

Comment: ok if I will use `Dim j As Integer = j + 1` inside the `for loop' then what should I expect

Comment: if u have assign j=1 then it should be 1,2,3 lik that

Comment: He already knows what *does* happen. He ran it in a debugger and checked that for himself before asking the question (which is good). What's he's asking here is ***why*** that happens.